# Routing fwmark to VPN gateway using nftables mark

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, openvpn, nftables

I'm trying to setup selective routing of a traffic filtered by IP address over OpenVPN on my OpenWRT router

I have an OpenVPN profile up and working with route-nopull option to disable setting default gateway.

The following commands are meant to have packets targeted to a set of ip addresses and marked with 0x1 mark in mangle prerouting section:

```
nft add set inet fw4 marker { type ipv4_addr \;}
nft add element inet fw4 marker {40.81.94.43}
nft insert rule inet fw4 mangle_prerouting ip daddr @marker counter meta mark set 0x1
```

Then I have an ip route table setup to route the marked packets through VPN gateway:

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table vpn
ip route add default via 10.211.1.118 dev tun_vpn table vpn
```

This setup doesn‘t work for some reason: the traffic just goes through a default wan gateway, although the nft counter shows packets get to the marking rule.

However if I explicitly set the routing table to be used for the ip address it works as expected:

```
ip rule add to 40.81.94.43 table vpn
```

directs traffic to 40.81.94.43 through the vpn gateway as intended

Seems either nft doesn‘t mark packets with 0x1 mark or `ip rule add fwmark 1` doesn‘t catch it for some reason.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've learned a LOT from this question, but since nftables configuration is not "a piece of cake" to everyone, I want to share my own config, I'll try to share as detailed as I can so someone might have a more intuitive idea on how to do pbr wi nftables:

#### Step 1, define a standalone nft table.

```
table inet classify {
    set pbrips {
            type ipv4_addr
            elements = { 1.0.0.1, 8.8.4.4,
                         8.8.8.8 }
    }

    chain output {
            type route hook output priority filter; policy accept;
            ip daddr @pbrips counter packets 29795 bytes 3021764 ct mark set 0x00000002
            ip daddr @pbrips counter packets 29795 bytes 3021764 meta mark set ct mark
    }

    chain prerouting {
            type filter hook prerouting priority mangle; policy accept;
            ip daddr @pbrips counter packets 193712 bytes 60796012 ct mark set 0x00000002
            ip daddr @pbrips counter packets 193712 bytes 60796012 meta mark set ct mark
    }
}
```

Here I defined a standalone table called classify, instead of using the existing `fw4` table of openwrt 23.05, I do this because I tried to manipulate directly on `fw4` table but it seemed to have no effect.

In the table I defined a nftset named `pbrips`, **with some pre-defined ips (in my case I'll always re-route these ips)**. In this set, each ip is designed to route to another interface instead of the default gateway, thus it's called policy-based-routing, i.e. pbr.

You may have noticed the **counter packets 29795 bytes 3021764** part, it's generated automatically by nftables, when you are creating rules, what you only need is a bare `counter` directive.

For some reasons I have to put two chains there, the `output` chain, and the `prerouting` chain, **please pay attention to the hooks used inside each chain, they are the key-points if you want to re-route traffic**, The reason I put two chains here is that If I only use the output chain, only the traffic (related to the 3 ips in the set) from the openwrt router itself can be re-routed, while with the prerouting chain all the traffic from my LAN can be correctly re-routed (p.s. If someone knows, please kindly remind me how to fix it Thks!)

#### Step 2, add a dedicated route table for pbr

Here is my `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables 
#
# reserved values
#
128     prelocal
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
123     pbr
```

You can see in the last row I put a new table there, with id `123` and name `pbr`, you can use whatever id and name here, just don't use the already existing ones above, they are system-level values. **you can edit this file directly with vi and save it**

#### Step 3, create a route in the table to receive all traffic

Here is my output of `ip route list table 123` (**n.b. you can refer to the table either by it's id or it's name, they are both OK**)

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ip route list table 123
default dev tun0 scope link 
root@OpenWrt:~#
```

As you can see, there is only one rule in table 123, and if you want to re-route all traffic through table 123, this route is sufficient.

#### Step 4, the critical step, create ip rule to consume the fwmark

Here is my output of `ip rule`

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local 
32765:  from all fwmark 0x2 lookup pbr 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 
root@OpenWrt:~#
```

And the keypoint here lies in the 3rd line, aka the `fwmark 0x2` part, here 0x2 refers to hex value 2, **but hex value 0x2 is equivalent to decimal value 2, and the value in my nft rule is `0x00000002`, because `0x00000002` is exactly the same hex value of `0x2`, and both equal to decimal value `2`**, I recommend you to always use a decimal value like 1,2,3, not 0x1,0x2,0x3, to not confuse yourself (as I did before)

#### Step 5, use whatever your preferred method to **add elements to the nftset**

As long as you add new elements (i.e. IPs) to the nftset `pbrips`, you can test it out through `traceroute 8.8.8.8` to verify if the pbr policy is working or not. Theoritically you are ready to go now.

And Thank you again Alexey Martemyanov for your question and your answer as a good reference to help me learning pbr!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case it could be useful for someone:

After finding "[SOLVED] iproute2 ignores connection marks set with nftables" thread I've updated the nft rules set to the following:

```
nft insert rule inet fw4 mangle_prerouting ip daddr @marker counter ct mark set 390
nft add rule inet fw4 mangle_prerouting ip daddr @marker counter meta mark set ct mark
```

And it worked!
Turns out I needed to set a connection mark not a meta mark

Comment: Can you comment on from where the 390 came?  That looks very different than 0x1.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the info, I followed the steps and successfully split specific traffic by their ip.

Comment: @FrankSamuelson 390 is the (decimal) number used to do load balancing in the referred article, in everyone's case it's different, in my case I use decimal value 2, which equivalents to hex value 0x2, in the above case the author uses `fwmark 1`, thus in the nftables rule it should read `ip daddr @marker counter ct mark set 1`, I think he uses 390 just because he wants to show the original case in the referred article. and the article link is here: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1136379-start-0.html